# Como validar una columna de datagridview para numeros?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Tengo un datagridview con varias columas pero quiero validar una para que solo se puedan escribir numeros y los demas columnas que se puede escribir lo quesea.

Tengo esto pero me bloquea toda la fila, no la columna que quiero.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
        dText.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
        dText.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
        }
    }

private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar una determinada celda en un GridView, se puede hacer uso de estos dos eventos:

- [CellValidating](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating?view=netframework-4.8): Ocurre cuando la celda pierde el foco de entrada (esto permite la validación, dado que cualquier evento se suprime).
- [CellValidated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidated?view=netframework-4.8): Ocurre después de que la celda ha terminado de validar.

Ahora, creamos una función llamada `ValidNumber` para que detecte si la celda tiene números o no. Su valor de retorno es de tipo `bool`, esto quiere decir que si la función devuelve un `true`, es porqué hubo un error, de lo contrario, si retorna un `false`, es porqué la celda si tiene un valor válido (en este caso debe ser un número).

```
        private bool ValidNumber(string value)
        {
            //Obtenemos la longitud de la celda
            int len = value.Length;
            for(int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
            {
                //Detectamos si la celda tiene únicamente números
                if(!(value[i] >= '0' && value[i] <= '9'))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Vamos asumir que la función `ValidNumber` está adentro de la clase `Form1`.

El uso de esta función sería:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Si es la primera columna y la celda es un número, la condición se cumple...
            if(e.ColumnIndex == 0 && ValidNumber(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Solo se puede ingresar números.";
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //Borra el mensaje de error cuando la validación termine...
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
        }
    }
    }
}
```